# Making a system call in GAS and using variables in .data section and accessing them for a system call inside another sub-routine

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

Here is the code example that I have written using GAS syntax for 64 bit intel assembly. When the code is run the expectation is to print out the string:    Inside the _print subroutine.

```
#This example is a an example to call a subroutine 
.global _start

.section .text

_start:

    call _print

_exit:   
    #exit call
    mov $60, %rax
    xor %rdi, %rdi

    syscall

_print:
    #set up the stack frame
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp

    # write syscall's parameter set up
    mov std_out_fd, %rdi
    mov $message, %rsi
    movq message_size, %rdx
    mov write_syscall_no, %rax

    syscall

    #Restore callers registers value
    #pop %rdx
    #pop %rsi
    #pop %rdi 

    #Destroy the stack frame:
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp

    ret


.section .data


std_out_fd: .int 0x02

message: .ascii "Inside the _print subroutine.\n"

message_size: .byte 30

write_syscall_no: .int 0x01
```

=========================================

When I try to use the declared variable 'message_size' as the third parameter for the write system call I get a few weird extra characters printed after the message is printed on the screen:

```
ali@alix2:~/Programming/asm/GAS-Syntax/SubRoutine$ as -o subroutine.o subroutine.s
ali@alix2:~/Programming/asm/GAS-Syntax/SubRoutine$ ld -o subroutine subroutine.o
ali@alix2:~/Programming/asm/GAS-Syntax/SubRoutine$ ./subroutine
Inside the _print subroutine.
`;`Qali@alix2:~/Programming/asm/GAS-Syntax/SubRoutine$
```

but when instead of using the variable I change it to
mov $30, %rdx

then it works perfectly and none of the extra characters(`;`Q)  will be written to stdout anymore.

```
ali@alix2:~/Programming/asm/GAS-Syntax/SubRoutine$ ./subroutine
Inside the _print subroutine.
ali@alix2:~/Programming/asm/GAS-Syntax/SubRoutine$
```

Could anyone explain the reason behind this? Thanks.

Comment: If you see your question comes out with broken formatting please use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61191024/edit) and the code formatting button on the toolbar to fix it yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movq message_size, %rdx` is a 64-bit (qword) load that include the `.byte 30`, and the `.int 0x1`, and 3 bytes past that.  Use a debugger (GDB for example) to look at values in registers.  And use `strace ./subroutine` to trace system calls and show that you're passing a huge length to `write`.

You could use a `movzbl message_size(%rip), %edx` load to zero-extend that byte into RDX.

**Or better, let the assembler calculate sizes for you as assemble-time constants with

`.equ message_size, . - message`** so you can use `$message_size` as an immediate.  No need to hard-code the size separately or to store it in data memory.

Same for the call number; don't do a 64-bit load for it, especially not from a 32-bit `.int`!  If you had any other stuff in `.data` after that, it would load garbage into the high bytes of RAX.  You *could* just `mov` into EAX which zero-extends into RAX implicitly.

Comment: You are a star. Thank you so much for your help and guidance. I knew how to do the calculation of the string length in NASM but I had no idea how to do it in GAS. I tried to look that up and google it for a few minutes but no joy. So if you have a link to a very nice website describing the GAS syntax and best practices I would really appreciate it if you could share that. Also if you know good books about GAS assembly could you please recommend some to me?

Comment: By the way I tried both of your recommendations and they both worked perfectly. But I prefer the latter one. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ is the upstream docs.  Looking at compiler output is another way to learn AT&T syntax, although usually they just output literal numbers everywhere because they're not trying to make maintainable source.  I don't know any books; I know that Programming from the Ground Up *uses* AT&T syntax (on 32-bit x86 Linux), but it's teaching asm in general.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info has some info and links.  IDK if https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax is any good.